# Why is sum(bigint) significantly faster than sum(integer) in PostgreSQL v10?

Tags: postgresql

```
create table t_num_type(
   n_bigint bigint,
   n_numeric numeric,
   n_int int
);

insert into t_num_type
select generate_series(1,10000000),
       generate_series(1,10000000),
       generate_series(1,10000000);
```

1» n_bigint

```
explain (analyze,buffers,format text)
select sum(n_bigint) from t_num_type;
Finalize Aggregate  (cost=116778.56..116778.57 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=1221.663..1221.664 rows=1 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=23090
  ->  Gather  (cost=116778.34..116778.55 rows=2 width=32) (actual time=1221.592..1221.643 rows=3 loops=1)
        Workers Planned: 2
        Workers Launched: 2
        Buffers: shared hit=23090
        ->  Partial Aggregate  (cost=115778.34..115778.35 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=1217.558..1217.559 rows=1 loops=3)
              Buffers: shared hit=63695
              ->  Parallel Seq Scan on t_num_type  (cost=0.00..105361.67 rows=4166667 width=8) (actual time=0.021..747.748 rows=3333333 loops=3)
                    Buffers: shared hit=63695
Planning time: 0.265 ms
Execution time: 1237.360 ms
```

2» numeric

```
explain (analyze,buffers,format text)
select sum(n_numeric) from t_num_type;
Finalize Aggregate  (cost=116778.56..116778.57 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=1576.562..1576.562 rows=1 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=22108
  ->  Gather  (cost=116778.34..116778.55 rows=2 width=32) (actual time=1576.502..1576.544 rows=3 loops=1)
        Workers Planned: 2
        Workers Launched: 2
        Buffers: shared hit=22108
        ->  Partial Aggregate  (cost=115778.34..115778.35 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=1572.446..1572.446 rows=1 loops=3)
              Buffers: shared hit=63695
              ->  Parallel Seq Scan on t_num_type  (cost=0.00..105361.67 rows=4166667 width=6) (actual time=0.028..781.808 rows=3333333 loops=3)
                    Buffers: shared hit=63695
Planning time: 0.157 ms
Execution time: 1592.559 ms
```

3» n_int

```
explain (analyze,buffers,format text)
select sum(n_int) from t_num_type;
Finalize Aggregate  (cost=116778.55..116778.56 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=1247.065..1247.065 rows=1 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=23367
  ->  Gather  (cost=116778.33..116778.54 rows=2 width=8) (actual time=1247.006..1247.055 rows=3 loops=1)
        Workers Planned: 2
        Workers Launched: 2
        Buffers: shared hit=23367
        ->  Partial Aggregate  (cost=115778.33..115778.34 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=1242.524..1242.524 rows=1 loops=3)
              Buffers: shared hit=63695
              ->  Parallel Seq Scan on t_num_type  (cost=0.00..105361.67 rows=4166667 width=4) (actual time=0.028..786.940 rows=3333333 loops=3)
                    Buffers: shared hit=63695
Planning time: 0.196 ms
Execution time: 1263.352 ms
```

pg9.6》

```
abase=# \timing
Timing is on.
abase=# select sum(n_bigint) from t_num_type;
      sum       
----------------
 50000005000000
(1 row)

Time: 2042.587 ms
abase=# select sum(n_numeric) from t_num_type;
      sum       
----------------
 50000005000000
(1 row)

Time: 1874.880 ms
abase=# select sum(n_int) from t_num_type;
      sum       
----------------
 50000005000000
(1 row)

Time: 1073.567 ms
```

pg10.4》

```
 postgres=# select sum(n_bigint) from t_num_type;
          sum       
    ----------------
     50000005000000
    (1 row)

    Time: 871.811 ms
    postgres=# select sum(n_numeric) from t_num_type;
          sum       
    ----------------
     50000005000000
    (1 row)

    Time: 1168.779 ms (00:01.169)
    postgres=# select sum(n_int) from t_num_type;
          sum       
    ----------------
     50000005000000
    (1 row)

    Time: 923.551 ms
```

After many tests Sum efficiency of pg10.4 was significantly improved, 9.6: sum(int)>sum(numeric)>sum(bigint), pg10.4: sum(bigint)>sum(int) : >sum(numeric)

Why after multiple tests pg10:sum(bigint)>sum(int)?
Does it mean that the bigint type is more recommended?

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to include a clearer description of the question in the body? The title refers to "the efficiency being increased significantly", but it's not clear what numbers we're comparing - are we comparing the execution time of these three queries, an unshown difference between Postgres versions, or something else?

Comment: Unrelated, but: your insert to generate the test data would be more efficient, if you used `generate_series()` in the from clause so the series only needs to be generated once, not three times: `insert into t_num_type
select n,n,n from generate_series(1,10000000) as t(n);`

Answer (score 0):

First, you should repeat the experiment several times to see if the difference remains the same. Caching and other effects cause a certain fluctuation in query times.

I'd expect the difference between `integer` and `bigint` to be negligible in the long run. Both summation operations should be implemented in hardware.

`numeric` should be significantly slower, because operations on these *binary coded decimals* is implemented in C in the database engine.

If `bigint` summation remains faster even in repeated experiments, my only explanation is *tuple deforming*: to get to the third column, PostgreSQL has to process the first two columns.

Comment: Yes, I found the difference between pg10.4 and pg9.6 after several tests

Comment: @dodo: I think Laurenz' suspicion with tuple deforming could be right. When I create three tables with just one column the sum on bigint is actually slower than on int (or even numeric which surprised me a lot). [plan for bigint](https://explain.depesz.com/s/rBO9) [plan for int](https://explain.depesz.com/s/e9Rb) [plan for numeric](https://explain.depesz.com/s/5Ozn)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Are you using the pg9.6 version?

Comment: @dodo: those plans were created with Postgres 11

Comment: @Laurenz Albe  Is a tuple deformation because n_numeric(storage main) is in front of n_int(plain).Does that mean it is more advantageous for the table to put the fields of int, bigint, and so on (storage plain) in front?Or jit?

Comment: Actually, @a_horse_with_no_name's test would refute the tuple deforming theory, which was unlikely to begin with. What you should do to find out what causes the difference: Run the test in a tight loop, maybe in several concurrent sessions, and use `perf top` to find out where the time is spent.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name What I tested on the pg11rc1 version was sum(int)>sum(bigint)>sum(numeric). [plan for int](https://explain.depesz.com/s/4Xo4) [plan for bigint](https://explain.depesz.com/s/niQI)  [plan for numeric](https://explain.depesz.com/s/Lk6P)